# $(2n)! $ v/s $(n!)^2$ v/s $ n^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> We are required to compare the three numbers i.e which one is the largest and which one is the smallest.

My attempt:

Since we are given three quantities, we can divide the problem into 3 smaller problems, Comparing $2$ quantities  at a time. Its trivial to prove that $(2n)! > (n!)^2$  and $(2n)! > n^n$, but its a little difficult to compare $(n!)^2$ and $n^n$. After experimenting with  some values for $n$, I came to the conclusion that $n^n < (n!)^2$ and then  tried to prove it with Mathematical Induction. But I got stuck in the Induction step/Induction hypothesis.

I need some help in the Induction step.

Comment: Really, $3^3>(3!)^2?$

Comment: Hint: Compare $(n+1-k)k$ and $n$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n.$

Comment: Hint:$(n!)^2=(1\cdot n)(2\cdot(n-1))\cdots(n\cdot 1)$.

Comment: Is $4^4=16^2>(4!)^2?$ @VVR What data points did you use? There are no $n$ such that $n^n>(n!)^2.$

Comment: If all you need is an asymptotic result, you may think of using Stirling's formula
$$
n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n.
$$

Comment: @PierreCarre: Thank you, but I am not familiar with Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 1):

For $n \geq 1$, $(2n)! > (n!)^2$:

$$
1 = 1 \\
2 = 2 \\
\vdots \\
n = n \\
n+1 > 1 \\
n+2 > 2 \\
\vdots \\
2n > n
$$

For $n \geq 3$, $(n!)^2 > n^n$:

$$
n \cdot 1 = n \\
(n-1) \cdot 2 > n \\
\vdots \\
2 \cdot (n-1) > n \\
1 \cdot n = n
$$

ETA: **Stinking Bishop** and **Thomas Andrews** alluded to this latter in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n) = n!^2$ and $g(n) = n^n$. We prove $f(n) \geq g(n)$ for all $n \geq 1$. A brief calculation tells us it is clearly true for $n=1,2,3$.

Now note $f(n+1)/f(n) = (n+1)^2$, where as $g(n+1)/g(n) = (n+1)(1+1/n)^n \leq (n+1)e$, where $e = 2.7128...$. Clearly thus whenever $n \geq 3 \geq e$ we have $f(n+1)/f(n) \geq g(n+1)/g(n)$. Thus $f(n) \geq g(n)$ means $f(n+1) \geq g(n+1)$ also.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
(n+1)^{n+1}-(n+1)!^2 = (n+1)^2\left((n+1)^{n-1}-n!^2 \right)\leq(n+1)^2\underbrace{(n^n - n!^2)}_{< 0} < 0.
$$

So, you are left with showing that $n^n \ge (n+1)^{n-1}\Leftrightarrow (1+1/n)^n \leq 1+n$.